# How do I pass an int from my main to method for calculations?

Tags: java, methods

Trying to create a program where user inputs 2 numbers in my main, a menu method displays to show what the user wants to do with those 2 numbers using a switch statement, then 4 other methods will do calculations depending on which option user selects from the menu.

My problem/question is how do I pass my 2 stored ints from my main to do calculations in my other 4 methods?

My solution was to move the process of asking for and inputting the 2 integers into my menu method, but my instructor specifically asked to pass the ints from main to methods.

Here's what I have so far. ***EDIT*** I know this code compiles and works, what I wanted was is the 5 lines of code asking for and getting the 2 integers inside my main instead of my menu method ***EDIT***

```
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {       

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);    //Allows input from keyboard
        int iMenu;                              //Holds menu 
        System.out.print ("\n\nPress ENTER to continue");
        kb.nextLine();
        iMenu = menu();                         //Calls menu method


    }


public static int menu()
{

        int iNum1;                              //Holds user input for number 1
        int iNum2;                              //Holds user input for number 2
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);    //Allows input from keyboard
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the first integer: ");
        iNum1 = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the second integer: ");
        iNum2 = kb.nextInt();

        int iSelection;                         //Holds menu selection
        System.out.println("\n\t M E N U ");
        System.out.println("\n1>Sum up two integers" +
        "\n2>Find the difference of two integers" +
        "\n3>Find the average of two integers" +
        "\n4>Find the product of two integers" +
        "\n5>Find the quotient of two integers");
        iSelection = kb.nextInt();
    //}     
        switch (iSelection)
        {
            case 1: 
                sumTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
                break;
            case 2:
                subTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
                break;
            case 3:
                avgTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
                break;
            case 4:
                multiTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
                break;  
            case 5:
                divTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
            }
            return iSelection;              //End menu()
        }
        public static int sumTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
        {
            int iSum;                       //Holds sum of iNum1 and iNum2
            iSum = iNum1 + iNum2;
            System.out.println(iSum);
            return iSum;                    //End sumTwoNumbers(int,int)
        }
        public static int subTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
        {
            int iSub;                       //Holds difference of iNum1 and iNum2
            iSub = iNum1 - iNum2;
            System.out.println(iSub);
            return iSub;                    //End subTwoNumbers(int,int)
        }
        public static double avgTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
        {
            double dAvg;                    //Holds average of iNum1 and iNum2
            dAvg = (iNum1 + iNum2) / 2;
            System.out.println(dAvg);
            return dAvg;                    //End avgTwoNumbers(int,int)
        }
        public static int multiTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
        {
            int iMulti;                     //Holds product of iNum1 and iNum2
            iMulti = iNum1 * iNum2;
            System.out.println(iMulti);
            return iMulti;                  //End multiTwoNumbers(int,int)
        }
        public static int divTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
        {
            int iDiv;                       //Holds quotient of iNum1 and iNum2
            iDiv = iNum1/iNum2;
            System.out.println(iDiv);
            return iDiv;                    //End divTwoNumbers(int,int)
        }
```

When I move (input the 2 integers) up to my main, I get loads of errors mostly "cannot find symbols on all my methods for example:

```
Proj2.java:78: error: cannot find symbol
                    avgTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable iNum1
  location: class Proj2
Proj2.java:78: error: cannot find symbol
                    avgTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
                                         ^
```

I'm assuming its because the int wasn't passed through to my methods correctly, but I'm at a loss as to how to do it.

Comment: Perhaps a basic understanding of Java will allow you to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the numbers as parameters to the `menu()` method:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{       

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);    //Allows input from keyboard
    int iMenu;                              //Holds menu 
    System.out.print ("\n\nPress ENTER to continue");
    kb.nextLine();

    int iNum1;                              //Holds user input for number 1
    int iNum2;                              //Holds user input for number 2

    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the first integer: ");
    iNum1 = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the second integer: ");
    iNum2 = kb.nextInt();

    iMenu = menu(iNum1, iNum2);                         //Calls menu method

}


public static int menu(int iNum1, int iNum2)
{
    /* rest of the menu code */
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So iMenu = menu(iNum1, iNum2) is where the inputted numbers are passed?

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I had compiling with this code was the `iNum1` and `iNum2` declared two times.

Let me also offer you a better syntax/convention :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Calculator
{
    public Calculator()
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("\n\nPress ENTER to continue");
        kb.nextLine();
        this.menu();
    }

    public int menu()
    {       
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the first integer: ");
        int iNum1 = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter the second integer: ");
        int iNum2 = kb.nextInt();

        int iSelection = 0;
        System.out.println("\n\t M E N U ");
        System.out.println("\n1>Sum up two integers"
                + "\n2>Find the difference of two integers"
                + "\n3>Find the average of two integers"
                + "\n4>Find the product of two integers"
                + "\n5>Find the quotient of two integers");
        iSelection = kb.nextInt();

        switch (iSelection)
        {
            case 1:
                Calculator.sumTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
                break;
            case 2:
                Calculator.subTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
                break;
            case 3:
                Calculator.avgTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
                break;
            case 4:
                Calculator.multiTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
                break;
            case 5:
                Calculator.divTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
            default:
                System.out.println("Option : " + iSelection + "not handled.");
        }

        return iSelection;
    }

    public static int sumTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
    {
        int iSum = iNum1 + iNum2;
        System.out.println(iSum);
        return iSum;                    //End sumTwoNumbers(int,int)
    }

    public static int subTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
    {
        int iSub = iNum1 - iNum2;
        System.out.println(iSub);
        return iSub;                    //End subTwoNumbers(int,int)
    }

    public static double avgTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
    {
        double dAvg = (iNum1 + iNum2) / 2;
        System.out.println(dAvg);
        return dAvg;                    //End avgTwoNumbers(int,int)
    }

    public static int multiTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
    {
        int iMulti = iNum1 * iNum2;
        System.out.println(iMulti);
        return iMulti;                  //End multiTwoNumbers(int,int)
    }

    public static int divTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
    {
        int iDiv = iNum1 / iNum2;
        System.out.println(iDiv);
        return iDiv;                    //End divTwoNumbers(int,int)
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Calculator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);    //Allows input from keyboard
    int iNum1;                              //Holds user input for number 1
    int iNum2;                              //Holds user input for number 2
    int iSelection;                         //Holds menu selection

    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the first integer: ");
    iNum1 = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the second integer: ");
    iNum2 = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("\n\t M E N U ");
    System.out.println("\n1>Sum up two integers" +
            "\n2>Find the difference of two integers" +
            "\n3>Find the average of two integers" +
            "\n4>Find the product of two integers" +
            "\n5>Find the quotient of two integers");
    iSelection = kb.nextInt();   
    doAction(iNum1,iNum2,iSelection);
}

private static void doAction(int iNum1, int iNum2, int iSelection) {
    switch (iSelection)
    {
    case 1:
        sumTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
        break;
    case 2:
        subTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
        break;
    case 3:
        avgTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
        break;
    case 4:
        multiTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
        break;
    case 5:
        divTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
    }
}

private static int sumTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
{
    int iSum;                       //Holds sum of iNum1 and iNum2
    iSum = iNum1 + iNum2;
    System.out.println(iSum);
    return iSum;                    //End sumTwoNumbers(int,int)
}

private static int subTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
{
    int iSub;                       //Holds difference of iNum1 and iNum2
    iSub = iNum1 - iNum2;
    System.out.println(iSub);
    return iSub;                    //End subTwoNumbers(int,int)
}

private static double avgTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
{
    double dAvg;                    //Holds average of iNum1 and iNum2
    dAvg = (iNum1 + iNum2) / 2;
    System.out.println(dAvg);
    return dAvg;                    //End avgTwoNumbers(int,int)
}

private static int multiTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
{
    int iMulti;                     //Holds product of iNum1 and iNum2
    iMulti = iNum1 * iNum2;
    System.out.println(iMulti);
    return iMulti;                  //End multiTwoNumbers(int,int)
}

private static int divTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
{
    int iDiv;                       //Holds quotient of iNum1 and iNum2
    iDiv = iNum1/iNum2;
    System.out.println(iDiv);
    return iDiv;                    //End divTwoNumbers(int,int)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I should've seen that, but according to my instructors instructions I need these 5 lines of code into my main, which is when i'm getting the errors.

Comment: Appreciate it, I did what Sizik had suggested and it all ran smoothly, I guess putting iMenu=menu(iNum1, iNum2) fixed what I was having a problem on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let `menu` accept parameters you want to pass to it. You can change signature of this method to something more like

```
public static int menu(int argument)
{
   //your code
}
```

and use it like

```
int parameter = ...
int result = menu(parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

What u have to do is to add parameter in your method and pass them from your main method

Take all the inputs in the main method and pass it to the method

```
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {       

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);    //Allows input from keyboard




            int iNum1;                              //Holds user input for number 1
            int iNum2;                              //Holds user input for number 2
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);    //Allows input from keyboard
            System.out.print("\nPlease enter the first integer: ");
            int iNum1 = kb.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\nPlease enter the second integer: ");
            int iNum2 = kb.nextInt();

            int iSelection;                         //Holds menu selection
            System.out.println("\n\t M E N U ");
            System.out.println("\n1>Sum up two integers" +
            "\n2>Find the difference of two integers" +
            "\n3>Find the average of two integers" +
            "\n4>Find the product of two integers" +
            "\n5>Find the quotient of two integers");
            iSelection = kb.nextInt();

    Create object of your class here and call the method dont knw whats ur class name so for eg
  class1 cl = new class1();
cl.menu(iNum1,iNum2,iSelection);
    }


    public static int menu(int iNum1,int iNum2,int iSelection)
    {

        //}     
            switch (iSelection)
            {
                case 1: 
                    sumTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    subTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    avgTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    multiTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
                    break;  
                case 5:
                    divTwoNumbers(iNum1, iNum2);
                }
                return iSelection;              //End menu()
            }
            public static int sumTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
            {
                int iSum;                       //Holds sum of iNum1 and iNum2
                iSum = iNum1 + iNum2;
                System.out.println(iSum);
                return iSum;                    //End sumTwoNumbers(int,int)
            }
            public static int subTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
            {
                int iSub;                       //Holds difference of iNum1 and iNum2
                iSub = iNum1 - iNum2;
                System.out.println(iSub);
                return iSub;                    //End subTwoNumbers(int,int)
            }
            public static double avgTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
            {
                double dAvg;                    //Holds average of iNum1 and iNum2
                dAvg = (iNum1 + iNum2) / 2;
                System.out.println(dAvg);
                return dAvg;                    //End avgTwoNumbers(int,int)
            }
            public static int multiTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
            {
                int iMulti;                     //Holds product of iNum1 and iNum2
                iMulti = iNum1 * iNum2;
                System.out.println(iMulti);
                return iMulti;                  //End multiTwoNumbers(int,int)
            }
            public static int divTwoNumbers(int iNum1, int iNum2)
            {
                int iDiv;                       //Holds quotient of iNum1 and iNum2
                iDiv = iNum1/iNum2;
                System.out.println(iDiv);
                return iDiv;                    //End divTwoNumbers(int,int)
            }
```